# Python WebDriver send_keys not working on element and returns ElementNotInteractableException

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to send some keystrokes using python webdriver to a p element that is attached to a js event listener. When i type the keys in manually, it works. However when I use driver.send_keys(), it returns an ElementNotInteractableException. The element is as follows:
`<p data-v-6779462c="" id="textBox" class="input"></p>`
My code to locate and send the keystrokes to the element is as follows:

```
input_area = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//p[@id="textBox"]')))
input_area.click()
input_area.send_keys(keys)
input_area.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

The full stacktrace is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "automation.py", line 32, in <module>
    input_area.send_keys(word)
  File "/home/server/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "/home/server/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/server/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/server/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.66)
```

I am using Chrome on Ubuntu Linux.
I need the way to solve this and why it is happening.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it is not `input` element??. However try with element_to_be_clickable  `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable ((By.XPATH, '//p[@id="textBox"]')))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P tag is a paragraph tag , you cannot Interact with it .

You should be sending keys to input tag

Try below code

```
input_area.click()
elemInput = driver.switch_to.active_element
elemInput.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```